# Unable to import custom module to other application (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have the following Project tree -

[image: Project Tree]

Following is my error log: [Error Log](http://pastebin.com/QJwKRn7r)

error arises on execution of command - python manage.py syncdb

[Test1>settings.py](http://pastebin.com/nVdhrhU7)

models.py for user_profile: [user_profile>models.py](http://pastebin.com/5YgV100c)

models.py for tweets: [tweets>models.py](http://pastebin.com/fu04nr0q)

Comment: What's in your user_profile.__init__.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to import `UserM` from `user_profile` module and not `user_profile.models`. You can either import everything to your `user_profile` module's `__init__.py` like following:

```
# add this to user_profile/__init__.py
from .models import *
```

or use the import statement as follows:

```
from user_profile.models import UserM
```

**Explanation:**

user_profile is a directory and as [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) suggest:

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

So `user_profile` is a directory not a module. By adding an `__init__.py` file to it you let python know that this is a containing package. But in `from user_profile import UserM` you are not specifying the module that contains the `UserM` class so python is going to look for this in the containing packages `__init__.py`.

With above suggested solutions you either import your `UserM` class to the `__init__.py` file, where python is looking it for according to the `from user_profile import ..` statement or you change the import statement and specify the module that contains your class by modifying it to `from user_profiles.modesl import UserM`.

Comment: Although i wanted to understand what you did with the __init__.py file above.

I coudn't understand whats happening there.

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer.